# Isn't this switch statement a nonsense?

Tags: php, laravel, switch-statement, laravel-5

I found this weird switch statement in [Laravel 5 core](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php#L205-L223):

```
switch (count($args)) {
    case 0:
        return $instance->$method();
    case 1:
        return $instance->$method($args[0]);
    case 2:
        return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1]);
    case 3:
        return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2]);
    case 4:
        return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3]);
    default:
        return call_user_func_array([$instance, $method], $args);
```

Is there any reason why they possibly decided to build such a thing instead of just using this?

```
return call_user_func_array([$instance, $method], $args);
```

Any benefits?

Comment: Maybe this was translated from a language that has function overloading. Or, they found that there was a slight performance gain in the most common cases (presumably where $args was 4 or less).

Comment: No this isnt nonsense ..language like c++ support this and its called function overloading, **Polymorphism** can be achieved through overloading

Comment: @NullPoiиteя But PHP doesn't have function overloading.

Comment: seems a little clunky to me, i'd be interested in knowing what's being done inside `$method`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO the programmer avoided to `call_user_func_array()` for a reasonable amount of typical calls to `$instance->method()`. Of course it is faster to call the method directly instead of using `call_user_func_array()`. The code was written with love :)

Comment: Perhaps Laravel soon requires PHP 5.6+, then they will be able to do this little fancy thing: `return $instance->method(...$args);`.

Comment: @RoboRobok I imagine the direct influence of this code is from [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php#100794) on the function in the PHP documentation. Github shows the code was originally committed in Jan 2010, so the author was more than likely worried about performance in PHP 5.3.

Comment: @patricus Good catch! Wondering why all the comments there are down-voted.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that there were functions with up to 4 arguments that expected pass by value instead of pass by reference.  Notice the note on the function documentation about pre PHP 5.4 usage.  [call_user_func_array docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)